# Is there any way to block user to access the urls not specified in urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to block the user access to the urls not specified in urls.py of django.

We have media and static file in django project.

If opened, the media and static files can be opened easily with the url.

Like if an image named *avatar.jpg* is in *http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/anime/images/*

Here a user can access this file typing the url

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/anime/images/avatar.jpg

Is there any way I can restrict all users to access the urls which are not specified in urls.py?

**In urls.py**

```
path('', views.index, name="AnimeHome"),
path('about/', views.about, name="About"),
path('watch/<int:animeId>', views.product, name="Watch"),
path('search/', views.search, name="Search"),
path('help/', views.help, name="Help"),
path('feedback/', views.feedback, name="Feedback"),
path('episode/<int:animeId>/<int:episodeNumber>',views.episode, name="Episode")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have likely configured these files to be served in your `urls.py`. [See "Serving files uploaded by a user during development" in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development). If you remove the

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

from your `urls.py` then media files will not be served.

Comment: As you said, I removed the static setting from urls.py and now media files are not being served.

Comment: Then please accept this as the correct answer.